# Python TypeError: str, int, float

Tags: python, types

I am getting the

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

for the last line below. I do not understand why.  Is this erroring on the values or the indices?

Assuming it's because of the values, I tried casting these values as `float` and `str`, but neither of these approaches fixes this error and instead I get TypeErrors of type int or str, depending on how I cast them.

I looked at several other Questions on StackOverflow with the same description, but none of these resolved my problems.  Can anyone help? Am I being clear enough?

```
def initialize_combined_scores(self):
    sum_weights = self.dist_weight + self.coc_weight + self.optimization_weight + self.productivity_weight
    normalized_dist_weight = self.dist_weight / sum_weights
    normalized_coc_weight = self.coc_weight / sum_weights
    normalized_optimization_weight = self.optimization_weight / sum_weights
    normalized_productivity_weight = self.productivity_weight / sum_weights
    self.combined_scores = normalized_dist_weight
    self.combined_scores_df = pandas.DataFrame({'WorkerID':self.worker_ids})
    self.combined_scores_df['WorkerClusterLat'] = [xx for xx,yy in self.worker_ll]
    self.combined_scores_df['WorkerClusterLon'] = [yy for xx,yy in self.worker_ll]
    for col_name in self.worker_col_keepers:
        self.combined_scores_df[col_name] = self.worker_df[col_name]

    for pidx, patient_id in enumerate(self.patient_ids):
        self.combined_scores_df[str(patient_id)] = self.combined_scores[:, pidx]
```

Comment: In the last line, what was `self.combined_scores[:, pidx]` intended to do?

Comment: `self.combined_scores` is `self.dist_weight / sum_weights`, which is some float.  `5.0[:, pidx]` isn't meaningful, which is why you get this error.

Comment: Thank you guys, "self.combined_scores[:, pidx]" creates a list of patients with there corresponding distances (combined_scores).  Each patient has one combined_score.  So from my understanding, ":" separates each item in the list.

Comment: Patrick, please see my comment below in response to Eike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.combined_scores` might be a `float`. I see the following lines in your code:

```
normalized_dist_weight = self.dist_weight / sum_weights
...
self.combined_scores = normalized_dist_weight
```

The names suggest that both `self.dist_weight` and `sum_weights` could both very well be `float`. The result of the division would then be a `float`.

**Edit:**

The last line can only work, if `self.combined_scores` is a multidimensional container. A `pandas.DataFrame` probably.

I think the error is in:

```
self.combined_scores = normalized_dist_weight
```

Something seems to be missing here. The similarly named `self.combined_scores_df` is bound to a `pandas.DataFrame` in the line below. I believe, a line that created a `pandas.DataFrame` and bound it to `self.combined_scores` was erroneously deleted.

Comment: Yes, both of the above are floats, so I thought that casting this as a float would fix this, but probably I didn't cast the correct values.  Assuming these are floats, how could I eliminate the errors?

Comment: The last line can only work, if `self.combined_scores` is a multidimensional container. Most probably a `DataFrame`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed!  That was a pandas.DataFrame.  Good observation.